# ArcGIS Versioning, Post & Reconcile, Compressing, and Lost in Space

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, versioning, reconcile

Here is the short version, and I'll post the long detailed version below.

I'm needing to figure out an easier way to post changes to the data on our SDE Geodatabase. Versioning is not setup, and the data posting process is horrendous.

I supposed to get on the GIS server, kill all GIS services manually, kill all remaining user connections manually, then using ArcMap, update the data and make changes, set as registered any files that need it, reapply privileges, and then restart GIS server services.

Assuming "versioning" will fix my problem and allow me to his "reconcile" and the "post" and then DONE then that is what I need help setting up with the pre-existing SDE geodatabase. ArcGIS 10.0 is what we have currently along with SQL Server 2008.

Long version: So we lost our GIS admin, and the person before the last admin actually setup the server. I don't think either of them really knew too much about what they were doing administratively and the server is most likely not working correctly. I have ZERO training with ArcGIS but have visited several places nearby with GIS. Every other place I've visited has a simple process of hitting two buttons: Reconcile & Post. There is no taking anything offline, or messing the SDE, or anything of the sort.

I'm struggling with these vague instructions left to me and I really need to figure out how to not only post data sent to me by GIS analysts, but how to properly setup and administrate our current server, until we go to 10.2 which a vendor will be setting up CORRECTLY from the ground up. I've found mentions of compressing databases in the help that ESRI provides, but I still haven't found a way to do it. The walkthrough doesn't seem to work on our setup. I'd really like to find out how to not only get versioning going, and users setup, but to get the GIS database maintained automagically.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, it seems like you've inherited a huge role!  Don't despair though... there are plenty of online resources to get you started.  I will say, however, that I would recommend you taking an online, instructor-led Esri geodatabase administration training course.  The course is not inexpensive, but it will do wonders for you in terms of where to start.

That being said, if you are going through all of what you described simply to make changes to your data on a regular basis, then I would say a versioned geodatabase is likely going to help you, although you may be able to get away with truncate/load of each object class depending on how data gets updated.  Without knowing all of your requirements and daily workflows for updating data along with your service publishing requirements, it' hard to prescribe an exact set of steps to go implement.  That being said, what you really want to avoid is deleting your feature classes in ArcSDE and then re-creating new ones from another source whenever changes have been made.  No wonder you have to kill connections and stop services!  That's painful.  Assuming everything is installed correctly and functioning as well as to be expected, you should educate yourself ASAP about how to use the software.

To get started, read about the following topics from Esri's online help: (1) versioning; (2) ArcSDE for SQL Server; (3) reconciling & posting edits.  Here are some links to point you in the right direction:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000t7000000
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_geodatabases_in_Microsoft_SQL_Server/002q000000n6000000/
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000w7000000

These topics will help you further explore other sections of the Esri help documentation.  You'll learn about additional topics like compress and conflicts, as well as the geoprocessing (GP) tools to perform truncate and GUIs for performing data loads.